# Can I use a Liebig condenser for condensing sulfuric acid?

Tags: distillation

I have a Liebig condenser but I read that the air cooled condenser is preferred for high temperature boiling points. My question is whether I can still use my Liebig with minimal risk... Should I just run it without coolant or even with warm water? There shouldn't be pressure build up if I just run it dry. If I used warm water though, I still have a huge temperature differential between the jacket and sulfuric acid vapour, not so much with just running it without coolant since there will be a gradient between the air temp from inner tube to outer tube.